# Partnerships and Standard normal moments

Tags: probability, combinatorics, random-variables

The solution to the problem 'How many ways are there to form partnerships among $2n$ people' is $\frac{(2n)!}{2^n n!}$

This is the same as the even moments of a standard normal distribution. Is that a coincidence? What is the relation between these two seemingly unrelated things?